# Currently I am using Bartender .NET SDK integration but I want to use "Rest API" instead. using c#, with .btw file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Currently I am using Bartender .NET SDK integration but I want to use "Rest API" instead. using c#, with .btw file ?

I need to change .NET SDK to Rest API integration...